# Несколько клиентских сессий RDP (без ввода пароля)

Tags: rdp

Для создания нескольких подключений к терминальному серверу со стороны клиента (без ввода пароля) можно использовать перенаправление IP адреса через файл `hosts`

Для тех кому известны другие способы, оставьте свои ответы. Особенно интересует создание хэша для пароля, чистой программы для этого так и не нашел.

Как многим известно, файл настроек храниться здесь: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Default.rdp`

Так как пароль в этом файле может сохраняться только один, мы не сможем таким способом организовать несколько клиентских подключений к сессиям терминального сервера.

Для обхода ограничения отредактируем файл: `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
192.168.0.1        ONENAME
192.168.0.1        TWONAME
```

В файле указываем IP адрес терминального сервера, и произвольное имя (имена должны отличаться друг от друга). Этим самым мы создаем перенаправление по именам на один IP адрес терминального сервера.

Теперь создадим два `.rdp` файла. Чтобы их создать нажимаем *"Сохранить как..."*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняем с нужными именами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жмем правой кнопкой мыши по значку, и выбираем *"Изменить"*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле *"Компьютер"* прописываем имя указанное в файле `hosts` (если у терминального сервера изменен порт для подключения, вводите его вместе с именем - `ONENAME:2299`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем установите флажок на *"Разрешить мне сохранять учетные данные"* и введите имя пользователя. Повторите эти действия для второго клиентского подключения используя второе имя `TWONAME:2299` указанное в файле `hosts`

После чего, можете работать сразу в двух окнах удаленного рабочего стола (без необходимости каждый раз вводить пароль).

=========================================================

Для очистки настроек от ненужных записей используйте ветку реестра: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`

=========================================================

Альтернативное решение (EN): [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989)

Ссылки по теме: [#1](http://www.raymond.pro/poleznye-programmy/skriptovanie/avtomatizacia-rdp-podklucenia) [#2](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/mstsc.html) [#3](http://it-enginer.ru/remote-desktop-connection-manager-utilita-dlya-upravleniya-rdp-soedineniyami/)

Comment: У вас юзвери скорее всего неправильно работают. ветка HKEY_CURRENT_USER и путь %USERPROFILE% будет разный для каждого пользователя. Проблема появится только если два и более пользователей работают из-под одной учётки? Или из разных учёток проблема сохраняется?

Comment: Юзер всего один, допустим бухгалтер, которому необходимо подключиться сразу к двум удаленным рабочим столам на одном IP адресе терминального сервера. Так как форма подключения может сохранить пароль только для одного IP адреса, придется его изменить в файле `hosts`. Если бы терминальных сервера было два, то проблем с сохранением пароля не возникло бы, из за разных IP адресов.